# Односкладні речення

Tags: пунктуація, синтаксис

Прислів'я та приказки, що мають один головний член речення, належать до узагальнено-особових речень.
Наприклад:"Вік живи - вік учись" належить до односкладних, узагальнено-особових речень.
А прислів'я "Немає краю без звичаю" належить до односкладних, безособових речень.

Чому саме так і як саме треба розрізняти ці два види односкладних речень?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Немає**](http://sum.in.ua/s/nema), **нема** - це не особова форма дієслова, а присудкове слово на позначення стану.

Якби це була особова форма **не має**, ми говорили б про ознаки 3 особи однини теперішнього часу. За правилами в узагальнено-особових реченнях така форма не зустрічається.

> В узагальнено-особових реченнях головний член (присудок) найчастіше
>   виражений дієсловом у формі 2-ї особи однини теперішнього чи
>   майбутнього часу (Багато будеш знати — швидко постарієш (Нар. тв.)).
>   Рідше значення узагальненої дії можуть передавати інші форми дієслова:
>   1) 1-а особа однини і множини (Що маємо, не дбаємо, а втративши,
>   плачемо (Нар. тв.)); 2) 2-а особа однини наказового способу (Не кажи
>   «гоп», доки не перескочиш (Нар. тв.)); 3) 3-я особою множини
>   теперішнього часу (За одного битого двох небитих дають (Нар. тв.)); 4)
>   форма чоловічого роду минулого часу (Цілив у ворону, а попав у корову
>   (Нар. тв.)). -

See more at: http://shkolyar.in.ua/uzagalnene-osobove-rechennya